# How to find a ranges of sequential numbers without gaps in a table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, gaps-and-islands

I am trying to find ranges of numbers without a certain value within a table grouped by a different identifier.
If i were to have a table like this:

```
ID | Type | Bad Value  | Bad Value 2
4  |  a   |    0       |     0
5  |  a   |    0       |     0
6  |  a   |    0       |     0
7  |  a   |    0       |     1
8  |  a   |    1       |     0
9  |  a   |    0       |     0
2  |  b   |    0       |     0
3  |  b   |    0       |     0
4  |  b   |    1       |     0
5  |  b   |    1       |     1
6  |  b   |    0       |     0
7  |  b   |    0       |     0
6  |  c   |    0       |     0
7  |  c   |    0       |     1
8  |  c   |    1       |     0
9  |  c   |    0       |     0
```

I would like to get an output like this:

```
FROM  |  TO  | Group
4     |  6   |   a
9     |  9   |   a
2     |  3   |   b
6     |  7   |   b
6     |  6   |   c
9     |  9   |   c
```

I found a similar solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19222589/how-to-find-serial-numbers-without-gap-in-mysql) but none of them work in Oracle. I get an error missing expression error.
Is there a way to go about doing this? The table in question will have several hundred thousand entries in it.

Comment: I don;t know ORacle, but this looks as if teh links to the sql code might help you out

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/find-sequence-gaps-using-oracles-analytic-functions/#

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30367988/330315

Comment: I forgot the link I intended to put in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to identify groups that are the same.  There is a trick to this, which is a difference of row numbers.

```
select min(id) as fromid, max(id) as toid, type
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (partition by type order by id) -
              row_number() over (partition by type, badvalue order by id)
             ) as grp
      from table t
     ) grp
where badvalue = 0
group by grp, type;
```

There is a nuance here, because you only seem to want rows where "bad value" is 0.  Note that this condition goes in the outer select, so it doesn't interfere with the `row_number()` calculations.

Comment: This works great, however i have one last question, if i were to have it check two different values as the badvalue instead of one, would that work? Would i just add another " - row_number() over (partition by type, badvalue2 order by id)?

Comment: @firereaction . . . I'm not sure what you mean.  Probably you would change the second `row_number()` to `partition by type, (case when badvalue in (a, b) order by id`.

Comment: I edited the original question to show what i mean. The second bad value is a different field. I would like it to subtract if either one is existing.